# Get maximum editor length that has been set by EM_LIMITTEXT

Tags: windows, winapi, sendmessage, editcontrol

Text limit of an edit control could be set by sending `EM_LIMITTEXT` Windows message.

Is there some way to **request** this parameter from an edit control?

Comment: [`EM_GETLIMITTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getlimittext) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [EM_GETLIMITTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getlimittext):

> **Parameters**
>
> **wParam**
>
> Not used; must be zero.
>
> **lParam**
>
> Not used; must be zero.
>
> **Return value**
>
> The return value is the text limit.

So you can try the following code to get the Text limit:

```
DWORD size = SendMessage(he, EM_GETLIMITTEXT, 0, 0);
```